# Not able to connect to azure from postman application - 403 forbidden error

Tags: azure-active-directory, postman, azure-rest-api, azure-subscription

I'm trying to GET [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups?api-version=2020-09-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourcegroups?api-version=2020-09-01) using postman application from my desktop.
For Authorization I passed the bearer token acquired from the response.

However getting the below error.

{
"error": {
"code": "AuthorizationFailed",
"message": "The client '02d899d6-c2d5-47d3-**********' with object id '02d899d6-c2d5-47d3-87b**********' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/read' over scope '/subscriptions/{{subscriptionId}}' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."
}
}

I'm not able to find this client id in my subscription to assign the role.
Where can I find this client id in the portal?
Also tried to register the postman app in my subscription but the create operation is greyed out.
Could anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results***

I registered one Azure AD application and granted **API permission** like below:

[image]

I generated **access token** via Postman using below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:<appID>
client_secret:<secret>
scope: https://management.azure.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used that token to list resource groups, I got **same error** as you like below:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subID>/resourcegroups?api-version=2020-09-01
```

**Response:**

[image]

The **client ID** in the error is the `ObjectID` of **service principal** associated with your Azure AD application having same name that can be found here:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Enterprise Applications -> All applications -> Select Application***

[image]

To **resolve** the error, assign **Reader** role to your service principal under your subscription as below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Subscriptions -> Your Subscription -> Access control (IAM) -> Add role assignment*

[image]

> **Note** that, you need to have either `Owner` or `User Access Administrator` role on your subscription to assign RBAC roles.

After assigning the role, I generated the **token** again and got the list of resource groups successfully like below:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subID>/resourcegroups?api-version=2020-09-01
```

**Response**

[image]